# Error when trying to have a variable pathsname: JSONPath must be a string literal or query parameter

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to use `JSON_EXTRACT` in Bigquery with a `JSONPATH` that is not always the same.

So my L.key is always a different keyword (which I have in table2). Unfortunately, `concat` with `JSON_EXTRACT` doesn't work for me.
If I use concat alone, without `JSON_EXTRACT`, it works.

This is the code I'm using:

```
SELECT A.*, SAFE_CAST(REPLACE(JSON_EXTRACT(A.some_json_obj, concat("$.", L.key)), '\"', '') AS NUMERIC) AS obp 
FROM table1 A, table2 L 
WHERE A.name = L.name
```

Comment: Hi @corianne1234, As state in the error message _JSONPath must be a string literal or query parameter at [8:8]_. What you are trying to do is related in a way to dynamic SQL capabilities which is not supported at the moment by BigQuery

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understand. But not even ...JSON_EXTRACT(query,concat("$.","xy"))... works and this is a string literal or am I wrong with this?

Comment: You are correct that the output of _concat_ function is literal but calling a function inside _JSON_EXTRACT_ is the issue you are facing. This is why when you do "$.xy" without _concat_ it's working fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

To work around BigQuery's 'limitation' for JsonPath, you can use custom function as in below example:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(json STRING, json_path STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
    try { var parsed = JSON.parse(json);
        return JSON.stringify(jsonPath(parsed, json_path));
    } catch (e) { returnnull }
"""
OPTIONS (
    library="gs://your_bucket/jsonpath-0.8.0.js"
);
SELECT A.*, 
  SAFE_CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(A.some_json_obj, CONCAT("$.", L.key)), r'["\[\]]', '') AS NUMERIC) AS obp 
FROM table1 A, table2 L 
WHERE A.name = L.name
```

Note : you need  download jsonpath-0.8.0.js from https://code.google.com/archive/p/jsonpath/downloads and upload it to your Google Cloud Storage bucket - in this example it is denoted as gs://your_bucket/jsonpath-0.8.0.js

For example, if to apply to below simplified dummy data

```
WITH table1 AS (
  SELECT 1 name, '{"x":1, "y":"2"}' some_json_obj
), table2 AS (
  SELECT 1 name, 'x' key UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'y'
)
```

result will be

```
Row name    some_json_obj       obp  
1   1       {"x":1, "y":"2"}    1    
2   1       {"x":1, "y":"2"}    2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a temporary workaround while we wait for BigQuery to allow dynamic SQL.

If you have the following table named **my_table**

| my_json_string | key |
| --- | --- |
| {"x":123,"y":45} | x |

then the following query should do the trick:

```
WITH cte1 AS
(SELECT my_json_string, key, ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(my_json_string, CONCAT('"', key, '":'))) as splits
FROM my_table)
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(SPLIT(my_json_string, CONCAT('"', key, '"'))[OFFSET(1)], r'(.*?)[,}]')
FROM cte1
WHERE splits = 2
```

It's essentially using the SPLIT function (that does not require a string literal) to do the extraction.