# Transform flat table into nested/repeated table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

in the BigQuery we have a **dictionary tables** which specify some mappings - example:

[image: flat table]

But this structure (flat, typically relational one) is not so handy to operate with mappings - when we write a query multiple joins are required if we would like to get mappings for a few fields. Our idea is to **transform dictionary table into one-row nested table** with repeated fields, to enable mappings application with a single join. So desired structure looks like:

[image: nested repeated table]

**Any idea how to transform the flat table to nested one via standard sql?** Essentially, values from `field` attribute should become a new attributes, and `key` `value` value pairs should became a repeated entries for each `attribute`. So the whole operation is similar to the pivot.

---

P.S.
I know, that BigQuery recently introduced a json structures. We considered this solution, but `JSON_QUERY` doesn't support passing concatenated values to function parameters. As a result we are unable to get values dynamically, and we resign from this solution as more complicated.
[Error when trying to have a variable pathsname: JSONPath must be a string literal or query parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55902047/error-when-trying-to-have-a-variable-pathsname-jsonpath-must-be-a-string-litera)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below simple option

```
select * from your_table pivot (
  array_agg(struct(key, value) ignore nulls) 
  for field in ('aaa','bbb')
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I have already applied the solution with `ARRAY_AGG` but with pivot seems even more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pivot` operator along with `array_agg()` function to achieve this.

Here is a query that does this -

```
with temp as 
(
    select 'aaa' as field, 1 key, 2 value union all
    select 'aaa' as field, 2 key, 5 value union all
    select 'aaa' as field, 4 key, 15 value union all
    select 'bbb' as field, 1 key, 23 value union all
    select 'bbb' as field, 2 key, 36 value
)

select * 
from 
(
select field, key, value
from temp
)
pivot
(
    array_agg(struct(key, value) ignore nulls) 
    for field in ('aaa','bbb')
)
```

In the pivot operator, as you can see, I have mentioned the field values as `aaa,bbb`. If you want to load them dynamically, then you will need to set a variable and then do it.

[image]

For more details on storing the values in variable and then using pivot, use this link - https://towardsdatascience.com/pivot-in-bigquery-4eefde28b3be

Comment: Thank you - this solution fully satisfy requirements.