# Selecting substrings from different points in strings depending on another column entry SQL

Tags: sql, string, google-bigquery, substring

I have 2 columns that look a little like this:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | {"ABC":1.0,"DEF":24.0,"XYZ":10.50,} | 1.0 |
| DEF | {"ABC":1.0,"DEF":24.0,"XYZ":10.50,} | 24.0 |

I need a select statement to create column C - the numerical digits in column B that correspond to the letters in Column A. I have got as far as finding the starting point of the numbers I want to take out. But as they have different character lengths I can't count a length, I want to extract the characters from the calculated starting point( below) up to the next comma.

`STRPOS(Column B, Column A) +5`    Gives me the correct character for the starting point of a SUBSTRING query, from here I am lost. Any help much appreciated.

NB, I am using google Big Query, it doesn't recognise CHARINDEX.

Comment: You may want to use SPLIT to split on the comma, and then again SPLIT to split on the colon.

Comment: Index of starting point STRPOS(Column B, '"'+ColumnA+'":') +strlen('"'+ColumnA+'":') +1 with any  ColumnA length

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression as well.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT 'ABC' ColumnA, '{"ABC":1.0,"DEF":24.0,"XYZ":10.50,}' ColumnB UNION ALL
  SELECT 'DEF', '{"ABC":1.0,"DEF":24.0,"XYZ":10.50,}' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'XYZ', '{"ABC":1.0,"DEF":24.0,"XYZ":10.50,}'
)
SELECT *,
       REGEXP_EXTRACT(ColumnB, FORMAT('"%s":([0-9.]+)', ColumnA)) ColumnC 
  FROM sample_table;
```

**Query results**

[image]

###### [Updated]

Regarding @Bihag Kashikar's suggestion: since`ColumnB` is an invalid json, it will not be properly parsed within js udf like below. If it's a valid json, *js udf with json key* can be an alternative of a regular expression. I think.

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION custom_json_extract(json STRING, key STRING)
RETURNS STRING 
LANGUAGE js AS """
  try {
    obj = JSON.parse(json);
  }
  catch {
    return null;
  }
  return obj[key];
""";

SELECT custom_json_extract('{"ABC":1.0,"DEF":24.0,"XYZ":10.50,}', 'ABC') invalid_json,
       custom_json_extract('{"ABC":1.0,"DEF":24.0,"XYZ":10.50}', 'ABC') valid_json;
```

**Query results**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this post too, this shows using js udf and with split options

[Error when trying to have a variable pathsname: JSONPath must be a string literal or query parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55902047/error-when-trying-to-have-a-variable-pathsname-jsonpath-must-be-a-string-litera)

Comment: yes, good point. *jsonpath* would be a good option for this problem.  unfortunately, `ColumnB` is not a valid json because of last comma in it, so js udf is not likely to work in this case without further modification.