# Query key-value pairs from json in bigquery into a key and value columns

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

I have a JSON column in bigquery as such

```sql
SELECT PARSE_JSON('{"a": [1,2,3], "b":[4,5,6]}') AS key_values;
```

[image]

Is it possible to write a query such that I can get the following?

I can have any number of keys so I cannot specify the key name in my query.

[image]

Seems like this should be really simple but I cannot figure it out :(

---

EDIT: Apart from the answer below, here are a couple native bq functions that I THINK were added recently.

Couple of new functions that I THINK were introduced recently.

[bqutil.fn.json_extract_values](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigquery-utils/tree/master/udfs/community#json_extract_values)

[bqutil.fn.json_extract_keys](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigquery-utils/tree/master/udfs/community#json_extract_keys)

Comment: Unless the set of a,b keys is fixed (where Barbaros' answer suffices) you will probably need to laterally unnest map keys and then array elements. This is AFAIK not possible using only built-in JSON functions in BigQuery, you can utilize custom Javascript functions, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59490036/653539) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57120586/653539).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cannot specify the key name in my query.

you can consider below.

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION json_keys(input STRING) RETURNS Array<String>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  return Object.keys(JSON.parse(input));
""";

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION json_values(input STRING) RETURNS Array<String>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  return Object.values(JSON.parse(input));
""";

WITH sample_data AS (
  SELECT '{"a": [1,2,3], "b":[4,5,6]}' AS key_values
)
SELECT k, v
  FROM sample_data,
UNNEST (json_keys(key_values)) k WITH offset JOIN
UNNEST (json_values(key_values)) v0 WITH offset USING(offset),
UNNEST (SPLIT(v0, ',')) v;
```

**Query results**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`UNNEST`** operator along with **`CROSS JOIN`** s to have flattened result such as

```
SELECT 'a' AS key, value
  FROM t,
       UNNEST(JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(json.a)) AS value
UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', value
  FROM t,
       UNNEST(JSON_QUERY_ARRAY(json.b)) AS value
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?sq=1039335939843:57d9173697c0435cbd03ad4ec224c4a8)</kbd>